# Why does this proof work?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In "Naive Set Theory" of Halmos (page 15) there is a claim that

> for each collection $\mathcal{C}$, other than $\emptyset$, there
>   exists a set $V$ such that $x \in V \text{ if and only if } x \in X$ for
>   every $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$

To prove this assertions the author writes

> $V = \{ x \in A: x \in X\text{ for every }X \in \mathcal{C}\}$

where $A$ is any particular set in $\mathcal{C}$ and says that

> the dependence of $V$ on the artbitrary choice of $A$ is illusory, in fact
>   $V = \{ x: x \in X\text{ for every }X \in \mathcal{C}\}$

Can someone explain me why the dependence on $A$ is illusory? And what is the point of writing it then? As I understand the author proves this due to the axiom of specification, though I can't understand how author just takes arbitrary collection and creates a set $A$ in it that "suddenly" contains elements defined by specification ($x \in X\text{ for every }X \in \mathcal{C}$), as I can show a lot of collections that don't have such set as an element. But the claim about illusion of dependence totally confused me. Please, clarify this for me. I will be very glad to hear any help or hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $x \in X$ for every $X \in \mathcal C$ **and** $A$ is an element whatever of $\mathcal C$, obviously $x \in A$. As you said, $A$ is needed by Specification ($\mathcal C$ is a collection, and thus not necessarily a set).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, can you elaborate the difference between collection and set if there is any? So the proof is just based on the axiom, right? And as $A$ is some set in $\mathcal{C}$, so there are elements that actually exist on which we can apply specification, as $A$ itself together with $\mathcal{C}$ exist, right? And it is enough to define subset $V$ by applying specification on the existing set? If it so, anyway, I can't then understand why the author says that the dependence is illusory. What makes it illusory? Because in the second case elements are not elements of some existing set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're misunderstanding the notation
$$ V = \{ x \in A: x \in X\text{ for every }X \in \mathcal{C}\}$$
when you write

> I can't understand how author just takes arbitrary collection and creates a set $A$ in it that "suddenly" contains elements defined by specification ($x \in X\text{ for every }X \in \mathcal{C}$)

But the set builder notation does not create the set $A$ and it doesn't assert that the elements of $A$ are all the $x$ such that $x\in X$ for every $X\in\mathcal C$.

Instead, what it says is

> $V$ consists of exactly those elements of $A$ that satisfy $\forall X\in\mathcal C\;(x\in X)$.

This may end up being all of the elements in $A$, or none of them or some of them; that would just lead to $V$ becoming larger or smaller.

In any case, if there would happen to be an $x$ that satisfies $\forall X\in\mathcal C\;(x\in X)$ but *is not* in $A$, that $x$ would not become a member of $V$ either. (But in this particular case there cannot be such an $x$, because $A$ is one of the possible $X$ that $x$ must be a member of).

The *meaning* of the set builder is just an abbreviation for
$$ V = \{\; x \;\;:\;\; x \in A\text{ and }(x \in X\text{ for every }X \in \mathcal{C})\;\}$$

We write the condition $x\in A$ to the left of the colon simply to visually emphasize that the condition on $x$, "$x \in A\text{ and }(x \in X\text{ for every }X \in \mathcal{C})$" has the particular shape where the Axiom of Specification guarantees that $V$ will exist as a set.

Indeed since $A\in\mathcal C$ it is easy to prove
$$x \in A\text{ and }(x \in X\text{ for every }X \in \mathcal{C}) \;\iff\; (x \in X\text{ for every }X \in \mathcal{C}) $$
so the only reason to *include* the $x\in A$ condition at all is to make the Axiom of Specification happy, and the result will be the same *no matter which* of the sets in $\mathcal C$ we choose to use as $A$.

Comment: "make the Axiom of Specification happy", ahah, thank you very much for the explanation. I really misunderstood the builder notation in this context. And the last part of explanation where you show the redundancy of the condition was really awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The Axiom of Comprehension allows us to assert the existence of the set of all and only those members of a set A that have some specified property. So for any $A \in C$ we have $$\exists  V_A=\{x\in A: \forall c\in C\;(x\in c)\}.$$ And since  $C\ne \phi$ we have $$\exists A\in C\; \exists V_A=\{x\in A: \forall c\in C\;(x\in c)\}.$$ The "illusion of dependence" is that it seems that $V_A$ depends on $A,$ but in fact $$\forall A,B\in C\;(V_A=V_B=\{x\in C:\;\forall c\in C\;(x\in c)\}).$$

Comprehension is a substitute for the earlier, failed,  Axiom of Abstraction (or Unlimited Comprehension) which asserts the existence of a set of all and only those things with a specified property, which is paradoxical. (E.g. Russell's Paradox.) In Comprehension we must first have a set $A,$ from which we can "extract" the set of members of $A$ that have some property.

Different authors use different names for it, such as Specification.

Comment: Another example of "illusory dependence": Let $<$ be  a well-order on a set $A.$ Then for $B\subset A$ the restriction of $<$ to $B$ is also a well-order. Proof: For $\phi\ne S\subset B,$ for any $s\in S$ ,let $s'=\{s\}\cup \{t\in S:t<s\}$ and let $M(s)=\min s',$ which exists because $\phi\ne s'\subset A.$  In fact it is easily shown that $\forall s_1,s_2\in S\;(\min s_1=\min s_2=\min S).$

Comment: Did you mean $(x \in c)$ everywhere, instead of $(x \in C)$?

Comment: Yes. Typos. Thanks.